# How to create a perforce workspace in a

Tags: linux, perforce, workspace, p4v, rhel6

I have just been allocated a RHEL 6.8 box, I'd like to set up a perforce workspace there. How can I set that up? I don't believe it has p4v installed there(maybe that's step 1). Any help or assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, installing p4 or p4v would be the logical first step.
You can find the downloads at https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix.
I recommend starting out with plain old p4, the command-line version,
because it is easy to follow the steps for a command-line interface
when getting started.

Documentation for setting up a workspace is at https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/p4guide/chapter.configuration.html#DB5-17566.

Setting up a workspace presumes that someone has already set up a Perforce server that you can use through your workspace.  You will want to get the server information from another user or the administrator. Earlier sections of the same documentation web page detail what to do with the server information once you have it.

Hope this helps.